# Telerik MVC DatePicker - Disable all future dates

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a **Telerik MVC DatePicker** :

```
<%: Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.Date)
                         .TodayButton()
                         .Max(DateTime.Now)
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { @onkeypress = "return allowNumbersWithDot(event);", @onpaste = "return false;" })
                        %>
```

By setting **Max** property, I get dates only till current date and all future dates are hidden. What I what is, enable all dates till current date and disable all future dates. i.e. user can see all dates but can select only till the current date.

Comment: You might consider using validation to serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Max property blocks the selection and appearance of all dates after the value set.  To get around this, try formatting your DatePicker with a client event handler like:

```
@Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.Date).ClientEvents(e => e.OnChange("onChange"))
```

and then add your validation with something like this:

```
function onChange(e) {
    var endDate = new Date(); // Your specific date
    if (e.value > endDate) {
        if (e.previousValue === null) {
            $(this).data("tDatePicker").value(null);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

More information about this technique can be found in the Telerik support forums at:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/datepicker---prevent-future-date-selection.aspx

Comment: Found one much easy solution. I replaced telerik.calender.min.js and telerik.datePicker.min.js with telerik.calender.js and telerik.datePicker.js in my script folder. And then set the max date. It works in exactly the same way as above.

Answer (score 2):

Minimum Date: Use it to set the smallest date, which the user can select.

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
                  .Name("DatePicker")
                  .MinDate(new DateTime(1900,1,1)))
%>
```

Maximum Date: Use it to set the biggest date, which the user can select.

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
                  .Name("DatePicker")
                  .MaxDate(new DateTime(2100,1,1)))
%>
```

Good Luck!