# Telerik MVC Disable DatePicker using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, telerik-mvc

I need to disable Telerik MVC Disable DatePicker. The problem is telerik mvc datepicker is added in dom using jquery html() function.

After it loaded in dom i have to disable it.

I couln't use "$("#AccountInformalHearingDate").data("tDatePicker").disable()" method.

i'm $("#AccountInformalHearingDate").data("tDatePicker") is undefined error.

```
  <pre>
          var userId = getUserId();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $Url.resolve("~/ClientSetup/ClientAccounts/UpdateAccountDetails"),
            data: { AccountId: accountId},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#AccountDetailsContainer').html( @(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
                    .Name("AccountInformalHearingDate")
                    .Value(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1)) 

                 if(userId == 10){     
                     $("#AccountInformalHearingDate").data("tDatePicker").disable();
                 }

            ));
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
  </pre>
```

But i'm getting control undefined error. Since i cannot disable telerik controls all behaviour without data() function

Comment: Please add some relevant code to your answer.

Comment: telerik-mvc-datepicker-disable-all-future-dates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216788/telerik-mvc-datepicker-disable-all-future-dates

Comment: I need to disable on load itself. Not on change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution for above question after researching telerik mvc documentation

Reason for the above problem is, Ajax returned html contents is not getting reference of registered java scripts. So on success of  ajax call we need manually register needed telerik scripts to access telerik mvc controls as like below"

```
var telerikScriptArray = new Array();
telerikScriptArray[0] = "/Content/Scripts/Telerik/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";
telerikScriptArray[1] = "/Content/Scripts/Telerik/telerik.common.min.js";
telerikScriptArray[2] = "/Content/Scripts/Telerik/telerik.calendar.min.js";
telerikScriptArray[3] = "/Content/Scripts/Telerik/telerik.datepicker.min.js";
telerikScriptArray[4] = "/Content/Scripts/Telerik/telerik.timepicker.min.js";
telerikScriptArray[5] = "/Content/Scripts/Telerik/telerik.combobox.min.js";

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: $Url.resolve("~/Ares/Controller/Action"),
     data: { AccountId: accountId},
     sucess:function(data){
         $.telerik.load(telerikScriptArray, function () {
            $("#controlID").data("tDatePicker").disable(); // Here you can access ajax returned telerik controls.             
        });
     },
     error:function(){
     }
});
```